# How to memoize the returned value of a custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My custom hook returns the same value( "tiny" or "small" or "medium" or "large") every time I change the screen size

```
type Sizes = "tiny" | "small" | "medium" | "large"
const screenSize :Sizes = useScreenSize()
```

I want to memoize the value it returns (like react.memo) how can I do that?

but react.memo doesn't work for hooks because It doesn't compare the returned value instead it compares the props.

```
import { useWindowSize } from "react-use";
function useScreenSize(): Sizes {
  const { width } = useWindowSize();
  const [sizeScreen, setSize] = useState<Sizes>();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (width < 600) setSize("tiny");
    else if (width < 800) setSize("small");
    else if (width < 1184) setSize("medium");
    else if (width < 2000) setSize("large");
  }, [width]);
  return sizeScreen;
}
```

Comment: please show useScreenSize

Comment: @Viet function useScreenSize(): Sizes {
  const { width } = useWindowSize();
  const [sizeScreen, setSize] = useState<Sizes>();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (width < 600) setSize("tiny");
    else if (width < 800) setSize("small");
    else if (width < 1184) setSize("medium");
    else if (width < 2000) setSize("large");
  }, [width]);
  return sizeScreen;
}

Comment: Are you saying that your `useScreenSize` hook always returns the same value? It seems the value should be "memoized" be virtue of being a state variable, it only changes if you call the state updater. You should check that `width` is updating when you expect it to.

Comment: @Drew Reese i want width just update useScreenSize hook not the return value of useScreenSize (the component that uses useScreenSize hook) because  it doesnt change very much it is just "tiny" or "small" or "medium" or "large". I want to memorize the returned value

Comment: It sounds like your question is "How do I memoize the returned `sizeScreen` value from `useScreenSize` hook" and I'm trying to say that value is "memoized" in the hook, it only changes when `setSize` is called, and `setSize` is called when `width` changes. This is why I asked if `width` was updating as expected. This is starting to seem like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Can you share with us why you are trying to memoize `screenSize` (*`sizeScreen`*)? Perhaps including a more complete/comprehensive code example will also help.

Comment: I have very big component that uses useScreenSize I have an img tag that depends on the size of the device ( it only shows image when the device is "small") when the page is still small the useScreenSize hook  makes the whole component to rerender because width  has changed but the sizeScreen is still "small" nothing has changed. i want the component to rerender when the returned value become "big" and I need to memorize "small" value to make this thing happened and optimize my component

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not use CSS and a media query to display the image only on mobile sized screens? In your hook though, what is changing to trigger a rerender? Are you sure this hook is the issue? The `useEffect` around updating the `sizeScreen` state will only fire callback if `width` has been updated, i.e. if it's a different value. If `width` isn't changing then the returned `sizeScreen` value also shouldn't change. From what I can tell I don't think this hook is the issue (without further context).

Comment: the image tag was just and example this is my function export function getImageSize( SizeScreen: breakPoint ): 5800 | 4118 | 3000 | 2100 { if (SizeScreen == "tiny") return 5800; else if (SizeScreen === "small") return 4118; else if (SizeScreen === "medium") return 3000; else if (SizeScreen === "large") return 2100; else return 3000; } it checks if the device is small and then return a number(image size).   in nextjs every image component <image/> should have size

Comment: I test the component and the hook was the problem sometimes width has changed but sizeScreen remained the same(it is still small or big) i want my component to listen to breackpoints instead of width value